# Convert raw query into laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have this written and working as a raw SQL query, but I am trying to convert it to a more Laravel eloquent / query builder design instead of just a raw query.

My table structure like this:

```
Table One (Name model)
______________
| id  | name |
|------------|
| 1   | bob  |
| 2   | jane |
--------------

Table Two (Date Model)
_________________________________
| id  | table_1_id | date       |
|-------------------------------|
| 1   | 1          | 2000-01-01 |
| 2   | 1          | 2000-01-31 |
| 4   | 1          | 2000-02-28 |
| 5   | 1          | 2000-03-03 |
| 6   | 2          | 2000-01-03 |
| 7   | 2          | 2000-01-05 |
---------------------------------
```

I am returning only the the highest (most recent) dates from table 2 (Dates model) that match the user bob from table 1 (Name model).

For instance, in the example above, I return this from my query

> 2000-01-31
>
> 2000-02-28
>
> 2000-03-03

Here is what I am doing now (which works), but i'm just not sure how to use `YEAR`, `MONTH` and `MAX` with laravel.

```php
DB::select(
  DB::raw("
    SELECT MAX(date) as max_date
    FROM table_2
    INNER JOIN table_1 ON table_1.id = table_2.table_1_id
    WHERE table_1.name = 'bob'
    GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
    ORDER BY max_date DESC
  ")
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code if any problem then,

```
DB::table('table_1')->join('table_2', 'table_1.id','=','table_2.table_1_id')
    ->select(DB::raw('MAX(date) as max_date'),DB::raw('YEAR(date) year, MONTH(date) month'),'table_1.name')
    ->where('name','bob')
    ->groupBy('year','month')
    ->orderBy('max_date')
    ->get();
```

If any problem with above code then  feel free to ask.